# How to access the data in fnRender?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am just starting out with the datatable jquery plugin.
before I dig deeper I have a question if this is possible:

I have a user list, some users have two phone numbers assigned.

In the data table I want to display a select box if the user has more than one phone number.

Which methods should I check? I understand that you can use fnRender to customize a cell.  But how can I access the json data in fnRender? () or is there another way? cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [mRender](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html) which is similar:

```
'aoColumns': [
            {
              'mData': 1,
              'mRender': function (data, type, row) {
                  var newSelect = '<select><option>' + row[1][0] + '</option><option>' + row[1][1] + '</option>';
              return newSelect;
           },
           ...
```

This is simplified version, but `row` is your returned json, in a 2d array to allow for multiple phone numbers.  You'd have to build a selectlist control and return the html.